# Repeat command and use of variable by turn in Netlogo

Tags: netlogo, repeat

I am stuck with repeat command. NetLog codes' examples couldn't help anymore. I want turtles to pick the value by turn assigned through "who" number and then move a step forward. I want turtles to repeat the same task 10 times. I appreciate any help.
I run the commands error appears in as;

Can't find element 3 of the list [0 1 0], which is only of length 3.
error while turtle 0 running ITEM
  called by (anonymous command: [ ?1 -> ask turtles with [ who = ?1 ] [ if item ticks turn = 1 [ fd 1 ] ] ])
  called by procedure GO
  called by Button 'Go'*
Here are the codes

```
turtles-own [turn]
To setup
  ca
  create-turtles 2
  [move-to one-of  patches
  ]
  reset-ticks
end

to go
   tick
  define-turn
  foreach [ 0 1]
             [ ?1 ->
               ask turtles with [who = ?1]
               [ if (item ticks turn) = 1  [fd 1 ]  ]]

end
to define-turn
   Ask turtle 0 [ repeat 10 [ set turn  [0 1 0] ]]
   Ask turtle 1  [repeat 10  [ set turn [0 0 1] ]]

end
```